# libcurl API upgrade issue with: `CURLcode' does not name a type

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to upgrade libcurl from older version to the newest stable on, 7.37.0.

They changed 'curl_base64.h' and because of that the compilation breaks.

I get the following error:

utils/libcurl/include/curl/curl_base64.h:25: error: `CURLcode' does not name a type
utils/libcurl/include/curl/curl_base64.h:29: error:`CURLcode' does not name a type
../src/Api.cc: In member function `ERRCC Api::UpdateFile(go, off, std::string&, bool)':
Api.cc:54: error:`SessionHandle' undeclared (first use this function)
Api.cc:54: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
Api.cc:54: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
Api.cc:54: error: `Curl_base64_encode' undeclared (first use this function)

I tried to add 'curl.h' as a header to API.cc, it didn't help.
I have 'curl_base64.h' in my headers.

the CURLcode is a enum defind in curl.h

Comment: "no matter what I do". Show a sample of what you do.

Comment: I tried to add 'curl.h' as a header to the API class it didn't helped.
also tried to find more relevant headers with no results.

Comment: That would be "describe". *Here is my code (ctrl+V) here is my compilation command (ctrl+V)* is "show".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'curl_base64.h' is not an external header file and thus no application should include it - doing so means you are on your own. It is not part of the API. The API is stable and documented, and the only public headers are in the curl/ directory after an installation.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for answering, you are doing great work with curl!
I need to use 'Curl_base64_encode' and 'Curl_base64_decode' that is why I'm using 'curl_base64.h' is there another way use those functions and still be a part of the API?

Comment: No. We've decided to not expose the base64 functionality in the API so you can't access those functions the "normal" way.